# Limit of a complex function to 1 from the left

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I have read online from two or three sources stating that the following limit is trivial, but I don't see how.

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$, take $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ for $\lambda^{2^m}=1$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ then: $$\lim_{r \to 1^-} f(r\lambda) = +\infty$$

Would a correct approach to be to express $z$ in terms of $rexp(i\theta)$ and take the limit as $r$ tends to $1$ from the left of $f(r\lambda)$ and somehow make a connection? I see no reason as to why this limit is 'trivial'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(r\lambda)^{2^n}$ term-wise. The first $m$ terms converge, so you can forget them. The rest of the terms are always positive and they all converge to $1$ as $r\to1^-$. Therefore their sum becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: Would it be possible to go into more detail about why the first $m$ terms converge and how all terms afterwards converge to $1$? If $\lambda$ is a complex number then how do you know that $\lambda^{2^n}$ converges to $1$? Maybe I'm just a bit tired not to see this aha, thank you for your help

Comment: The function $r\mapsto(r\lambda)^{2^n}$ is continuous, so it converges as $r\to1^-$. For $n>m$ you have $(r\lambda)^{2^n}=r^{2^n}\cdot\lambda^{2^n}=r^{2^n}\to1$.