complex analysis - Prove $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^n}$ is not regular on the boundary of the unit cycle
I have been trying to solve this exercise for days now, I would really appreciate some help:
Let $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined in the open unit disc. A point $w \in \partial D$ is called a regular point for $f$ if there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $w$ and a holomorphic function $g$ such that $f = g$ on $U \cap D$.
Prove that the function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^n}$ is not regular at $z$ for any $z \in \partial D$.
I have tried proving it directly by the definition of a regular point, I have tried proving by contradiction, nothing seems to work.

This is proved in Rudin's RCA. See the chapter on Analytic continuation.

Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266832/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063374/42969

If $w_0^{2^n}=1$ for some natural $n,$ the series $f(w_0)$ diverges. Use this to show that $\lim_{w\to w_0} f(w)$ does not exist when taking the $w$ from the interior of the disk. Then use that the set of such $w_0$ is dense in the boundary.

If a power series  $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n z^{p_n}$, is such that $1=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ and
$p_{n+1}>\Big(1+\frac1\lambda\big)p_n$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, for some integere $\lambda>0$, then every point in the boundary of convergence $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a singular point. This is a Theorem by Hadamard.

Details to all facts stated in this posting are covered in many  books on Complex Analysis, for example Rudin W., Real and Complex Analysis, third Edition, McGraw Hill, 1986., or Simon, B., Basic Complex Analysis 2A, AMS, 2015.

@ThomasAndrews yes that was the direction I was going for, but when I tried applying convergence tests to prove that for every w on the boundary of the unit cycle f(w) does not converge, nothing worked for me. Do you have an idea?
